# How to add Font Awesome on recent post widget in Blogger?

Tags: html

I want to add `fa-caret-right` icon with red color in recent post widget before the post title. The code is given below.

Code:

```
[  
 <script>
    var numposts =10; 
    var showpostdate = false; 
    var showpostsummary = false; 
    var numchars = 100; 
 </script>
 <script 
src="MY WEBSITE/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=rp">
 </script>       
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you've given enough information for anyone to help you too much, but the usage for `Font Awesome`, and for `fa-caret-right` would include making the stylesheet available, and then using the class(es), such as below:

```
....
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" ../css/font-awesome.min.css">  
....
</head>  
<body>  
<i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i> 
....
```